# SVM allocation in OpenCL C++

Tags: c++, opencl

In the case of `cl_context` and `cl::Context`, we can do:

```
cl::Context context_ = cl::Context(device);
cl_context context = context_();
```

Now, I have an OpenCL program, with the following snippet in it:

```
...
void* svm_data = clSVMAlloc(context, svm_flags, svm_buffer_size, 0);
...
```

I would like to do something similar here to what we did with `cl::Context` above (i.e. extract the underlying variable from the header, or in this case, the underlying void pointer):

```
cl::SVMAllocator svm_data_ = cl::SVMAllocator<int, cl::SVMTraitAtomic<>>(context);
void* svm_data = svm_data_();
```

However, after looking through the [docs](https://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/classcl_1_1_s_v_m_allocator.html), I have been unsuccessful in finding a method.

Anyone got some ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'what we did with `cl::Context` above'?

Comment: sure, ill make an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to allocate the shared virtual memory using the allocator to get the pointer to it:

```cpp
cl::SVMAllocator<int, cl::SVMTraitAtomic<>> svm_allocator(context);

std::size_t num_elements = 4;
int* svm_data = svm_allocator.allocate(num_elements);
```

The SVM allocator holds only the context and the flags that are passed to `clSVMAlloc()` and if you want to allocate the shared virtual memory, you need to call `allocate()` method directly. Also, if you want to deallocate the allocated memory, you need to use the allocator as well:

```cpp
svm_allocator.deallocate(svm_data, num_elements);
```

Comment: This worked, ty.